# Left Join has an "unknown column" error

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM `placement_ans` A, `placement_quiz` B
left join `placement_time` C on (A.state=C.state)
where
A.no_place=C.no_place and A.no_stu=C.no_stu and A.no_place=B.no_place and A.place_q=B.no_q and YEAR(A.place_date) = YEAR(curdate()) and MONTH(A.place_date) = MONTH(curdate()) and A.no_place=208 and A.no_stu=793 order by A.place_q ASC
```

the error is 
Unknown column 'A.state' in 'on clause'

I also tried using

```
SELECT *
FROM `placement_ans` A, `placement_quiz` B
left join `placement_time` C on (placement_ans.state=C.state)
where
A.no_place=C.no_place and A.no_stu=C.no_stu and A.no_place=B.no_place and A.place_q=B.no_q and YEAR(A.place_date) = YEAR(curdate()) and MONTH(A.place_date) = MONTH(curdate()) and A.no_place=208 and A.no_stu=793 order by A.place_q ASC
```

but it doesn't seem to want to work

i have a table like

```
placement_time
state   num
100     10
```

and

```
placement_ans
state   something
100     11          
100     22          
55      33          
22      55          
33      77
```

and i want to print out a table thats

```
placement_ans
state   something    num
100     11           10
100     22           10
55      33           null
22      55           null
33      77           null
```

Comment: It means there's no such column in that table. Unless you add it, you can't make it work.

Comment: There IS a column called "state" in the table placement_ans

Comment: The database tells you that there isn't. Check again by using `SHOW CREATE TABLE placement_ans`. No matter what query you come up with, if the database says there isn't such a column, then there isn't such a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put your left join sequence like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM placement_ans A
left join placement_time C on (A.state=C.state),
placement_quiz B
where
A.no_place=C.no_place and A.no_stu=C.no_stu and A.no_place=B.no_place and A.place_q=B.no_q and YEAR(A.place_date) = YEAR(curdate()) and MONTH(A.place_date) = MONTH(curdate()) and A.no_place=208 and A.no_stu=793 order by A.place_q ASC
```

Comment: do one thing 1st remove 3rd table i.e. placement_quiz and where block from your query. check it is working or not gradually add ono-one conditions further to get your desire result

Comment: hey, you removed your comment, pls reply me back whether it is working or not

Comment: It does run though, but doesn't output the desired result, i'll try playing around with it more

Comment: check with your where condition section. Put the conditions with proper precedence order you will get your desire result

Answer (score 1):

From the given example data set and expected result you do not need to refer the table `placement_quiz`, it could be done as

```
select a.*,b.num from placement_ans a
left join placement_time b  on b.state = a.state
```